# Function for a sphere

Tags: functions, surfaces, spheres

I believe that there is something fundamentally wrong with my understanding of functions but I can't pin point what it is, so I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

Consider a unit sphere, centered at the origin, with equation: 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=1\,.
$$

Now we can re-arrange this and arrive at a function $z(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, which we can graph and this is the graph of a surface of a sphere, correct? Is it correct to call $z$ a function for the surface of the unit sphere? I have been searching "function for a sphere" online and this doesn't seem to be a term which makes me think I am fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: Spheres, just like circles in $R^2$, aren't functions since there are points in its domain which give *more than one output.* Functions should only return one output point at most; since the equation outputs $2$ values for $z$ for every input of $x$ and $y$ (with a few exceptions in its domain), then it is not a function. If I were searching for it I would use 'equation of a sphere' or something similar, but not function.

Comment: A function of $(x,y)$ is a rule which gives one specific value of $z$ for each pair $(x,y)$.  This is not the case in your example because of the $\pm$.  However you could define two separate functions$$z_1=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\quad\hbox{and}\quad z_2=-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you very much. So is it correct to say that $z_1=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is a function for the top half of the unit sphere?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the stereographic projection.

Comment: Yes. $z_1$ is the top half, if you choose to define up as the postive $\vec z$.

Comment: Plus-or-minus anything is never a single well-defined single-value function. Moreover, in this case, it is better to think of a sphere as being the *set* (for some $R \geq 0$) $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2 \}$. That should eliminate some confusion- you can manipulate the function as you desire, but the final thing being considered is not a function, but a set of points.

Answer (score 3):

Sphere is a *level set* of the function $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$. For example, $F(x,y,z)=1$ corresponds to the sphere of the radius $\sqrt{1}$. Being a 2-dimensional object one can locally re-parametrize it with two *independent coordinates*, for example in the top semi-sphere, simply by $x, y$, from which $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the *graph* of a function with the function itself. It is easier to see it in less dimensions:

The unit circle is a subset of plane consisting of points $\left(x,y\right)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$. If you isolate $y$, you get two functions: $$y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ and $$y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ The *graph* of the first function is a subset of the plane, equal to the upper part of the unit circle, and the graph of the second function is the lower part of the unit circle.

For the unit sphere, we also have two functions; one for the upper part of the sphere, containing the north pole, and another for the lower part, containing the south pole. If you unite the graph of both functions, you will get the whole unit sphere.